# How to log to the Logs-Window of VSTS Release Management from within a xUnit-Test?

Tags: logging, azure-devops, xunit, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

In our VSTS Release Management Script, we run xUnit-Tests. 
In the Logs Window under my release I see things like:

```
2017-03-08T17:19:39.8364561Z Information: [xUnit.net 00:00:00.9224776]       
Starting...
....
....
```

How can I log from within my xUnit-Test to that window?

Answer (score 0):

Anything printed on the standard output will be shown on that output window of the release.

Note that you will be able to write a specific [commands](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) that the build&release agent would intercept and execute, for example you could print a specific warning/error with the `task.logissue` command:

```
##vso[task.logissue type=error;sourcepath=consoleapp/main.cs;linenumber=1;columnnumber=1;code=100;]this is an error
```